# How to use bound XAML property in UserControl?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I have my own `UserControl`

```
 <local:MyUserControl MyProperty="{Binding myString}"/>
```

and I'm binding `myString` to it. Now I want to use it in my `UserControl`. I have `DependencyProperty` defined in my `UserControl`:

```
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(value);//writes nothing, null
            SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to do some things with this string. But it's always null.

Comment: Try RelativeSource like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077377/usercontrols-datacontext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Debug.WriteLine(value);` writes nothing not because the value is `null`. The getter and setter of a dependency property are not guaranteed to be run, while using `{Binding}`, the setter of your property is not called. You can add a break point in the setter to test it.

Please note following caution in [Custom dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185582.aspx#implementing_the_wrapper):

> In all but exceptional circumstances, your wrapper implementations should perform only the GetValue and SetValue operations. Otherwise, you'll get different behavior when your property is set via XAML versus when it is set via code. For efficiency, the XAML parser bypasses wrappers when setting dependency properties; whenever possible, it uses the registry of dependency properties.

Instead of reacting in the setter of your property, you can add a property changed handler in the original call to `DependencyProperty.Register` and in this handler you can act on the new value. For example:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChanged));

private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)e.NewValue != (string)e.OldValue)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

If you want to use the bound string in your `UserControl`, you can use `MyProperty` of the `UserControl`. For example:

In your `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl Name="root" ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty, ElementName=root}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Then when you use `<local:MyUserControl MyProperty="{Binding myString}"/>`, your `UserControl` will show the value of `myString`.

Comment: Thanks, but lets say I have two properties MyProperty and MyProperty2 both strings, and I want pass them to other method do some maniupulations on them and then update UI of MyUserControl from this method. While OnPropertyChanged is static I cant call non-static methods from this event.

Comment: Without your code, I can't help you further. I think you need to ask a new question with your updated code.

Answer (score 1):

If you used c# naming conventions - fields are camelcase - you bound this stuff to a field (*myString*). It's not working. You have to bind to a property (Pascalcase - get;set; ...etc).
In this case, you have a binding error in your output window.

Default setup of dependency property is *OneWay* binding which means if usercontrol changes the string it does not reflect in DataContext.

Change your binding to *TwoWay*

```
<local:MyUserControl MyProperty="{Binding myString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or change your DependencyProp to *TwoWay* mode:

```
DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```