# Binding Dependency Property of UserControl to MainWindow ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, viewmodel, dependency-properties

Allow me to simplify the problem to its basic blocks.

I have a UserControl1 in my project. It has a TextBox like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextProperty}"/>
```

In the code-behind, I have a dependency property like this:

```
public string TextProperty
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextPropertyProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And the constructor of the UserControl is simply

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();  
    DataContext = this;  
}
```

In the MainWindow, I have this:

```
<userctrl:UserControl1 TextProperty="{Binding ABC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PQR, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Now, in the viewModel of the MainWindow, I have:

```
    private string _abc;
    public string ABC
    {
        get { return _abc; }
        set 
        { _abc = "20";
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _pqr;

    public string PQR
    {
        get { return _pqr; }
        set
        {
            if(value != _pqr)
            {
                _pqr = value;
                ABC = PQR;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, even the UserControl is supposed to replicate whatever I write in the textbox, right?

But it doesn't. I have set breakpoints at setter of ABC. It gets updated, but that update does not reach the UserControl. My gut says that the binding is failing silently, and it's because I have set the `DataContext` to `this` in the constructor of UserControl.

How am I supposed to solve it?

**The Actual Scenario:**

Here is the XAML for the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyDiskTools.UserControls.NodeGrid.NodeGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyDiskTools.UserControls.NodeGrid"             
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding InputCommand}"/>
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>                
                <Style.Triggers>                    
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"/>
                    </Trigger>                    
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="0" Rows="1">
            <Button Content="A" />
            <Button Content="B" />
            <Button Content="C" />
            <Button Content="D" />
            <Button Content="E" />
            <Button Content="F" />
        </UniformGrid>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Rows="1">
            <Button Content="G" />
            <Button Content="H" />
            <Button Content="I" />
            <Button Content="J" />
            <Button Content="K" />
            <Button Content="L" />
            <Button Content="M" />
        </UniformGrid>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="2" Rows="1">
            <Button Content="N" />
            <Button Content="O" />
            <Button Content="P" />
            <Button Content="Q" />
            <Button Content="R" />
            <Button Content="S" />
            <Button Content="T" />
        </UniformGrid>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="3" Rows="1">
            <Button Content="U" />
            <Button Content="V" />
            <Button Content="W" />
            <Button Content="X" />
            <Button Content="Y" />
            <Button Content="Z" />
        </UniformGrid>
        <TextBox Name="InputMessage" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" Background="Beige" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding PasswordDisplay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class NodeGrid : UserControl
{
    public NodeGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        InputCommand = new InputCharacterCommand(this);
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public string PasswordDisplay
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordDisplayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordDisplayProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordDisplayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PasswordDisplay", typeof(string), typeof(NodeGrid), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    private ICommand _inputCommand;

    public ICommand InputCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputCommand;
        }

        set
        {
            _inputCommand = value;
        }
    }


    public void AddCharacter(string input)
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            PasswordDisplay = string.Concat(PasswordDisplay, input);
        }
    }

    public bool InputAllowed()
    {
        if (PasswordDisplay == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (PasswordDisplay.Length < 50)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}

class InputCharacterCommand : ICommand
{
    private NodeGrid _vmodel;

    public InputCharacterCommand(NodeGrid vm)
    {
        _vmodel = vm;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return (_vmodel.InputAllowed());
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vmodel.AddCharacter(parameter as string);
    }
}
```

And here is how I use it in my MainWindow:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="Enter PIN"/>
        <TextBox CommandManager.PreviewCanExecute="HandleCanExecute" Foreground="Transparent" MinWidth="100" Padding="10,0" Text="{Binding PIN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    <customlock:NodeGrid  MinHeight="250" MinWidth="500" PasswordDisplay="{Binding NodeGridDisplay}"/>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Unlock!"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The Code-behind:

```
private void HandleCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut ||
        e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
        e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

}
```

And now, the ViewModel:

```
    private string _PIN;

    public string PIN
    {
        get
        {
            return _PIN;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != _PIN)
            {
                _PIN = value;                    
                OnPropertyChanged();
                NodeGridDisplay = HashIt(_PIN);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _nodeGridDisplay;

    public string NodeGridDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return _nodeGridDisplay;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _nodeGridDisplay)
            {
                _nodeGridDisplay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }                
        }
    }

    private string HashIt(string input)
    {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input))).GetHashCode().ToString();
        }
    }
```

What is the intended function?

Let me illustrate it.

[The Lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKgoB.png)

One can enter the PIN, the hash of which will be displayed in the NodeGrid. Then the user will click the letters which will be concatenated with the hash. Then the user can click unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ElementName` in your `UserControl` or use RaltiveResource to find it, and you should not use DataContext = this. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171922/5615980) and [this link](http://mutelight.org/datacontext-in-a-custom-control))

Give your userControl a name and write:

```
<UserControl x:Class= ......
      Name="userControl">
     <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName = userControl}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Please note that you should use `Text` instead of `TextProperty` and make sure to change `_abc = "20"` to `_abc = value`.

Comment: Sorry for the `_abc = "20"`. I was using it to see if it worked with constant value.

Comment: Maybe the description of the problem I gave was too simplistic. My situation is a bit more, well, complex. I have edited my question to illustrate my particular problem.

Comment: Same as your simple example. Use ``ElementName`` in this part ``Text="{Binding PasswordDisplay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"``.  Other things seems fine.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! This problem has been irking me for too long. Using ElementName somehow didn't seem to work, maybe I was doing something wrong, but using RelativeSource did the trick!